# Passing a signal name into a verilog task

Tags: variables, signals, task, verilog

Instead of this task just toggling tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.vbiash high and low ten times I would like to be able to call it passing in any signal tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.vbiasl, tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.vbiasx, or tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.vbiasz and make them toggle as well. For example toggle_signal(tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.vbiasl);  Is it possible to do this.  If so I would really appreciate an example of how I would accomplish this.

```
task toggle_signal;

begin

  for (monpad_index=0; monpad_index < 10; monpad_index = monpad_index + 1)

  begin

    #1000;

    force tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.vbiash = 1'b1;

    #1000;

    force tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.vbiash = 1'b1;

    #1000;

  end

end
```

Comment: I formatted your code for you - just add four space to the beginning of each line in a block of code. I copied it exactly from the image which referenced `vbiash` twice.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pas the name of a single to a task. But you can create a macro to do this.

```
`define toggle_signal(sig) \
  for (monpad_index=0; monpad_index < 10; monpad_index = monpad_index + 1) \
  begin \
    #1000 force tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.sig = 1'b1; \
    #1000 force tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.sig = 1'b0; \
    #1000; \
  end
```

and then write

```
`toggle_signal(vbiash)
`toggle_signal(vbiasl)
```

Comment: That kind of works.  I can define the toggle signal and then call `toggle_signal(vbiash) in the task and it works, but I have to hard code that line in the task.  If I try to define a string that is passed into `toggle_signal so I can make this dynamic it still fails and I'm back in the same spot.  Am I doing something wrong or does verilog just not allow me to make this dynamic and there is no way around it.

Comment: thanks @dave_59 ! a small question: is this considered good practice?

Comment: That's not a small question. `force` is usually a statement of last resort, but sometimes there is no other choice. And hierarchical references can be difficult to manage as the design develops, but sometimes there is no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid do dive into a little C programming, you could write your own PLI/VPI. I suggest checking out [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html)'s sections on PLI/VPI (§ 36, 37, & 38). Your come may looks something like the following (Note, the code is a starting reference. I haven't tested it):

```
static int my_vpi_force_release_calltf(PLI_BYTE* user_data) {
  vpiHandle sys, argv, signal;
  p_vpi_value p_value;
  int force_release;
  force_release = (int) user_data;
  sys = vpi_handle(vpiSysTfCall, 0);
  argv = vpi_iterate(vipArgument, sys);
  signal = vpi_handle_by_name(vpi_get_str(vpi_scan(argv), 0);
  if (force_release != 0 ) {
    vpi_get_value(vpi_scan(argv), p_value);
    vpi_put_value(signal, p_value, 0, vpiForceFlag);
  } else {
    vpi_get_value(signal, p_value);
    vpi_put_value(signal, p_value, 0, vpiReleaseFlag);
  }
  return 0;
}
void register_my_vpi_force_release()
{
    s_vpi_systf_data data;
    data.type      = vpiSysTask;
    data.calltf    = my_vpi_force_release_calltf;

    data.tfname    = "$my_force";
    data.user_data = (PLI_BYTE8 *) 1;
    vpi_register_systf(&data);

    data.tfname    = "$my_release";
    data.user_data = (PLI_BYTE8 *) 0;
    vpi_register_systf(&data);
}
```

You can call your PLI/VPI tasks in verilog:

```
task toggle_signal( input [80*8-1:0] path_str );
integer index;
begin
  for (index=0; index < 10; index = index + 1)
  begin
    #1000;
    $my_force( path_str, 1'b1);
    #1000;
    $my_force( path_str, 1'b0 );
    #1000;
  end
  $my_release( path_str );
end
endtask
...
initial begin
   ...
   toggle_signal( "tb.stimulus.top.Ichip0.vbiash" );
   ...
end
```

---

If you don't want to write your own custom PLI/VPI, then I suggest enabling SystemVerilog and include [UVM](http://accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm) (the major simulators have UVM build in, or download it yourself). The UVM library has a build in method `uvm_hdl_force`/`uvm_hdl_release`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The following code passes a signal name as a parameter to a task then prints the signal name as a string. Tested in `iverilog`.

```pascal
reg this_is_some_signal_name;


`define NAME(net) `"net`"

task print;
    input reg [32*8] str;
    begin
        $display(">>> %0s", str);
    end
endtask


initial begin
    print(`NAME(this_is_some_signal_name));
    $finish;
end
```

Outputs:

```
>>> this_is_some_signal_name
```